# Convert metaheuristicOpt Package from R to Python

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, data-analysis

I've been working on converting PSO algorithm in metaheuristicOpt package from R to Python. I've finished converting it exactly the same from the original R version but when i tried to run both of them, it's shows very different result. I don't know what else to do because the code is exactly the same.

here is the converted source code : https://github.com/ilhaaamn/dna-barcoding/blob/master/dna-barcoding.py

please help
Thanks!

Comment: You must learn how to test your code. Execute each line or equivalent small chunk of code in each language version until you find the point that's different. I guess it has do to with some small semantic variation in expected behavior between languages or a bit of logic or implementation that was overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the line 160 (np.random.seed(1)) to the top of the file or after the line (import numpy as np).

And why would you want to convert from R to Python? You can simply find the Python library for it.

You can check out my dev version here:
https://github.com/thieunguyen5991/metaheuristics

Or my library here:
https://github.com/thieunguyen5991/mealpy

My implementation is very to understand and also line by line followed the paper.